# Reinstall CS4's photoshop's Floodlight in filter/render/lighting effects/style/floodlight

Tags: adobe-photoshop, imac

I inadvertently deleted a "came-with-Photoshop-plug-in" in Photoshop Menu/Filters/Render/Lighting Effects/Style(pull down menu)/Floodlight. I hit the delete button whilst in Floodlight, and Floodlight disappeared from the menu. It seems to be gone forever. I tried restarting, and I tried using Time Machine, but it seems deleting a plug-in affects all the Photoshops in Time machine. How do I get Floodlight back into Filter/lighting Effects/Style? I have CS4. iMac-OS10.6.8
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe adding [this](http://www.mediafire.com/?bz1929ksjr57e4z) back to your `Plug-ins\Filters\Lightning Styles` folder will solve your problem.